# Is there any solution available for VSTO Add-in support for Mac operating system?

Tags: macos, vsto, outlook-addin

I don't know whether it supports VSTO Add-in to Mac(iOS) operating system.

Can anybody please suggest me about MAC have to support VSTO Add-in? If it doesn't mean, what I should use to create a project which supports both Windows and Mac(iOS)?

Answer (score 0):

VSTO add-ins are based on COM technology which works only on Windows OS. MAC and IOS are not supported. Try developing Web Addins for Office. Checkout https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/learning-path-beginner